# Can I define multiple paginations on a single page?

Tags: categories, pagination

I have a category page, which shows this category's subcategories.

I want in each subcategory to show its first five articles. And then provide pagination for each subcategory in order to allow user to see next/previous articles of this subcategory.

How can I do this?

Comment: Not impossible, but would be extremely convoluted to implement. Could you elaborate why you want such nested pagination rather than simply linking to corresponding archive pages?

Comment: My portal users need to click on a master category and the contained sub-categories are listed. Each sub-category may contain 50-100 posts. So they ask if paging on those subcategories is possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, try calling [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) in each loop either on the last iteration, or prior to making the cleanup call.

There is a chance though that it will simply attempt to paginate the current page, rather than lead to a specific archive, so it would make more sense to add a link to the relevant archive instead.